# is there any way we can post image on facebook using facebook app on access allowed user's wall on be half them/app endless?

Tags: php, facebook, api, facebook-graph-api

Is there any way we can post image on facebook using facebook app on access allowed user's wall on be half them/app ?

We have this to get access of user for a one time and then whatever user upload will automatically post to their post wall.

We have tried this by storing the user access token but it will expire after 2 months.

So if there is any option to generate no expire token, then it would also work.

Comment: You are not allowed to upload stuff “automatically” to user timelines – the user has to trigger every single upload.

Comment: Yah that we actually want.To store the user token into the database and we can post on behalf of user. We are able to do so but token gone be expire after 2 month...

Answer (score 0):

As you already figured out, long-lived access token will expire after 60 days, which should be more than enough for most use cases.

In your case, posting to user's timeline after **they** take an action (and their consent) should work fine as all you need to do is request a new token. And if you use the Javascript SDK, this will be done in the background. More about this [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens#refreshtokens).